# What's the purpose of these red lines in edit mode?

Tags: modeling

What for are these red lines in that [model](https://free3d.com/3d-model/shark-324077.html)?

They don't seem selectable

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: They are seams to assist with UV unwrapping.

Comment: https://youtu.be/Y7M-B6xnaEM